# Why do they use "be" in titles of videos like "something be like"?

Tags: meaning, subjunctives

[image]

A lot of videos on Youtube have a title like "something be like". But why do they use "be" instead of "is" there? Is this a type of the present subjunctive form or anything by any chance?

Comment: No, this is [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English).

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's been "[memified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_meme)" and is no longer unique to AAVE, if it ever was. In any case, quite right that it is not proper standard English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a kind of meme or slang, not standard English.  Using **be** like this where standard English would use **are** is an example of the [*habitual be* or *invariant be*](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/invariant-be), which is a feature of African-American Vernacular English (although not entirely limited to African Americans).  Using the *invariant be* means that this is the normal condition of something, or that this is a hallmark of the thing, so it means something like

> Tests are always like ______

or

> _____ is typical of tests.

Again, this is not standard English, and as a learner you should probably not use it, because people might think you were mocking them.